# Не могу понять как использовать переменные

Tags: javascript, jquery, переменные

Не могу понять как использовать переменные
html, files_path после отработки функции

```
'$('.upload_files').on( 'click', function( event ){...}'
```

пробую например вывести в консоль console.log($html) внутри 
этой функции

`$(".add2cart").click(function () {...}`

выдается ошибка "Uncaught ReferenceError: $html is not defined"

Ниже весь код:

```html
$(window).ready(function () {
 (function($){

var files; // переменная. будет содержать данные файлов

// заполняем переменную данными файлов, при изменении значения file поля
$('input[type=file]').on('change', function(){
 files = this.files;
});


// обработка и отправка AJAX запроса при клике на кнопку upload_files
$('.upload_files').on( 'click', function( event ){

 event.stopPropagation(); // остановка всех текущих JS событий
 event.preventDefault();  // остановка дефолтного события для текущего элемента - клик для <a> тега

 // ничего не делаем если files пустой
 if( typeof files == 'undefined' ) return;

 // создадим данные файлов в подходящем для отправки формате
 var data = new FormData();
 $.each( files, function( key, value ){
  data.append( key, value );
 });

 // добавим переменную идентификатор запроса
 data.append( 'my_file_upload', 1 );

 // AJAX запрос
 $.ajax({
  url         : '/wp-content/themes/basic-pro/submit.php',
  type        : 'POST',
  data        : data,
  cache       : false,
  dataType    : 'json',
  // отключаем обработку передаваемых данных, пусть передаются как есть
  processData : false,
  // отключаем установку заголовка типа запроса. Так jQuery скажет серверу что это строковой запрос
  contentType : false,
  // функция успешного ответа сервера
  success     : function( respond, status, jqXHR ){

   // ОК
   if( typeof respond.error === 'undefined' ){
    // файлы загружены, делаем что-нибудь

    // покажем пути к загруженным файлам в блок '.ajax-reply'
    
    var files_path = respond.files;
    var $html = '';
    $.each( files_path, function( key, val ){
      $html += val +'<br>';
    } )

    $('.ajax-reply').html( $html );
   }
   // error
   else {
    console.log('ОШИБКА: ' + respond.error );
   }
  },
  // функция ошибки ответа сервера
  error: function( jqXHR, status, errorThrown ){
   console.log( 'ОШИБКА AJAX запроса: ' + status, jqXHR );
  }
 });
 $(".add2cart").click(function () {
  description = "";
  if ($("[data-id=" + $(this).data("id") + "]").hasClass("descriptionField")) {
   $(".descriptionField[data-id=" + $(this).data("id") + "]").removeClass("error");
   if ($(".descriptionField[data-id=" + $(this).data("id") + "]").val() < 8) {
    $(".descriptionField[data-id=" + $(this).data("id") + "]").addClass("error");
    return false;
   } else {
    description = $(".descriptionField[data-id=" + $(this).data("id") + "]").val();
    // description = description + " www ";
    console.log($html);
   }
  }
  $('#basket').removeClass('close-basket');
  $('button.add2cart[data-id=' + $(this).data("id") + ']').fadeOut();
  $('p.descriptionField-p[data-id=' + $(this).data("id") + ']').fadeOut();
  $('.descriptionField[data-id=' + $(this).data("id") + ']').fadeOut();
  $('.selectPrice[data-id=' + $(this).data("id") + ']').fadeOut();
  $('button.showFields[data-id=' + $(this).data("id") + ']').fadeIn();
  $('button.showFields[data-id=' + $(this).data("id") + ']').addClass('added');
  $('button.showFields[data-id=' + $(this).data("id") + ']').after('<i></i>');
  $.ajax({
   method: "post",
   url: "/ajax/common.php",
   data: ({
    action: "add2cart",
    name: $(this).data("name"),
    price: ($(".selectPrice[data-id=" + $(this).data("id") + "]").val() > 0 ? $(".selectPrice[data-id=" + $(this).data("id") + "]").val() : $(this).data("price")),
    descr: description
   }),
   success: function () {
    showcart();
    messageShowAddBasket("<p>Услуга добавлена<br><button onclick='showbasketlist(true);'>перейти в корзину</button></p>");
   }
  })
 });

});

 
})(jQuery);

});
```

Comment: Следующий вопрос будет: "Почему обработчик `$(".add2cart").click(...` выполняется несколько раз?".

Comment: Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow. Этот ресурс работает в режиме - вопрос/ответы. Не следует коренным образом менять текст/заголовок вопроса, это делает уже данные ответы бессмысленными. Задайте новый вопрос. Так же считается хорошим тоном отмечать самый полезный ответ как принятый щелчком по знаку "галочка" слева от ответа.

Comment: Хорошо, учту, я тут новечёк

Answer (score 1):

`files` вы догадались объявить вне функций событий и переменная доступна.
Надеюсь натолкнул на мысль